# prototypes javascript

Tags: javascript, prototipos

Hola buenas qeurria saber como desde mi main.js acceder a la tarjeta a borrar pero llamando al metodo deleteCard en cuestion

```js
// MAIN
$(document).ready(function(){
    initBtnListeners();
});

function initBtnListeners(){
    $('#add-card-btn').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        
        $title       = $('input[name="title"]').val();
        $image       = $('input[name="imageUrl"]').val();
        $description = $('input[name="description"]').val();
        
        var card = {
            title: $title,
            image: $image,
            description: $description,
        };
        var card1 = new Card(card).addCard();
        $('#create-card-form')[0].reset();
        
        $(document).on('click', '.btn-delete-card', function(card1){
            card1.deleteCard();
        });
    });
    
}

//CARD PROTOTYPE
function Card(card){
    this.title = card.title;
    this.image = card.image;
    this.description = card.description;
}

Card.prototype.addCard = function(){
    var duplicate = $('#templates > [data-element="card"]').clone();
    duplicate.find('.card-title').text(this.title);
    duplicate.find('.card-img-top').text(this.image);
    duplicate.find('.card-text').text(this.description);
    this.current = duplicate;
    $('#cards-container').append(duplicate);   
};

Card.prototype.deleteCard = function(){ 
    $(this.current).remove();
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>JQuery - Tutorial</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row mb-5">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3">
                <h1>Create Card</h1>
                <form id="create-card-form">
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text">
                                <i class="fa fa-tag"></i>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="Enter title">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text">
                                <i class="fa fa-image"></i>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="imageUrl" placeholder="Enter Image URL">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text">
                                <i class="fa fa-comments"></i>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" placeholder="Description">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-actions">
                        <button id="add-card-btn" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Add Card</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12">
                <h1>Cards List</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="cards-container">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3" data-element="card">
                <div class="card">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit, quasi. Fugit inventore natus repellendus explicabo tempora hic consectetur ipsum aliquid eos non ut est, vel, ipsam deleniti atque libero eius!</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-delete-card">Delete</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <div id="templates" style="display: none;">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3" data-element="card">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit, quasi. Fugit inventore natus repellendus explicabo
                        tempora hic consectetur ipsum aliquid eos non ut est, vel, ipsam deleniti atque libero eius!</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-delete-card">Delete</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
        <script src="./card.js"></script>
        <script src="./index.js"></script>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tienes dos problemas:

- `var card1 = new Card(card).addCard();`

  Aqui deberias dividirlo en dos filas para mantener `card1` como la instancia de `Card`.

  ```
  var card1 = new Card(card)
  card1.addCard();
  ```
- `$(document).on('click', '.btn-delete-card', function(card1){`

  Aqui estás pasando a la función un parametro `card1` y luego cuando haces `card1.deleteCard();` no reconoce el `card1`  de tu instancia si no el parametro que es undefined porque en el metodo `on` para la funcion no necesitas pasar parametros.

Para el problema que mencionas de que borra todos los duplicados es porque el evento `.on("click")` lo aplicas al `document` y le dices que borre sobre la instancia anteriormente creada.

La solucion es, usar la propia `card` para que el evento esté enlazado a esa tarjeta usando `$(card1.current).on(...`

Quedaría asi:

```js
// MAIN
$(document).ready(function() {
  initBtnListeners();
});

function initBtnListeners() {
  $('#add-card-btn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $title = $('input[name="title"]').val();
    $image = $('input[name="imageUrl"]').val();
    $description = $('input[name="description"]').val();

    var card = {
      title: $title,
      image: $image,
      description: $description,
    };
    var card1 = new Card(card)
    card1.addCard();
    $('#create-card-form')[0].reset();

    $(card1.current).on('click', '.btn-delete-card', function() {
      card1.deleteCard();
    });
  });

}

//CARD PROTOTYPE
function Card(card) {
  this.title = card.title;
  this.image = card.image;
  this.description = card.description;
}

Card.prototype.addCard = function() {
  var duplicate = $('#templates > [data-element="card"]').clone();
  duplicate.find('.card-title').text(this.title);
  duplicate.find('.card-img-top').text(this.image);
  duplicate.find('.card-text').text(this.description);
  this.current = duplicate;
  $('#cards-container').append(duplicate);
};

Card.prototype.deleteCard = function() {
  $(this.current).remove();
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>JQuery - Tutorial</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row mb-5">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3">
        <h1>Create Card</h1>
        <form id="create-card-form">
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <span class="input-group-text">
                                <i class="fa fa-tag"></i>
                            </span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="Enter title">
          </div>
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <span class="input-group-text">
                                <i class="fa fa-image"></i>
                            </span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="imageUrl" placeholder="Enter Image URL">
          </div>
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <span class="input-group-text">
                                <i class="fa fa-comments"></i>
                            </span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" placeholder="Description">
          </div>
          <div class="form-actions">
            <button id="add-card-btn" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Add Card</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12">
        <h1>Cards List</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="cards-container">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3" data-element="card">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit, quasi. Fugit inventore natus repellendus explicabo tempora hic consectetur ipsum aliquid eos non ut est, vel, ipsam deleniti atque libero eius!</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-delete-card">Delete</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div id="templates" style="display: none;">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3" data-element="card">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit, quasi. Fugit inventore natus repellendus explicabo tempora hic consectetur ipsum aliquid eos non ut est, vel, ipsam deleniti atque libero eius!</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-delete-card">Delete</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="./card.js"></script>
  <script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```